# Repeal first function with second function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function `translation()` which translates some parts of the contents.

I would like the reverse those translations when `stopTranslation()` is activated. I want to do it without simply reloading the page. I tried using `return` but the way I put it didn't work.

So, when you click on the first button, it activates function `translation()` and the text of `<p>` changes.
When the second button is clicked I want text that was changed by the first button to be changed back to normal. It should undo the first function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="translation()">ENG</button>
  <button onclick="stopTranslation()">SRB</button>
  <p id="a">Some text</p>
  <script>
    function translation() {
      document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }

    function stopTranslation() {}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'll have to remember the text you're overwriting by reading `innerHTML`, then later put that text back by writing it back to `innerHTML`.

Comment: that's really a low-quality post. Don't understand your problem

Comment: Ok, I'll edit it to explain better.

Comment: It might help if you used an alternative to 'repeal' -- do you mean replace, or stopped, or ...?

Comment: I've editted your answer to what I think you're asking.

Comment: @mrblewog Stop, cancel, undo what it has done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to remember the text you're overwriting by reading `innerHTML`, then later put that text back by writing it back to `innerHTML`.

For instance, you might remember the old content as a `data-*` attribute on the element:

```
function translation() {
    var element = document.getElementById("a");
    element.setAttribute("data-text", a.innerHTML);
    a.innerHTML = "Hello World";
} 
function stopTranslation() {
    var element = document.getElementById("a");
    var text = element.getAttribute("data-text");
    if (text) {
        a.innerHTML = element.getAttribute("data-text");
        element.removeAttribute("data-text");
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function translation() {
    var element = document.getElementById("a");
    element.setAttribute("data-text", a.innerHTML);
    a.innerHTML = "Hello World";
} 
function stopTranslation() {
    var element = document.getElementById("a");
    var text = element.getAttribute("data-text");
    if (text) {
        a.innerHTML = element.getAttribute("data-text");
        element.removeAttribute("data-text");
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="translation()">ENG</button>
<button onclick="stopTranslation()">SRB</button>
<p id="a">Some text</p>
```

---

Side note: I strongly recommend not using `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. Use modern event handling instead ([`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and such).

Comment: Thanks man, it works. I just wish there was a shortcut though. I need this for manually translating the entire website.

Comment: There is one thing that I just noticed. When the first button is clicked twice, it blocks any changes after that.

Comment: @SasNarSak - It only stores to a single slot. If you click the first button again, it overwrites that. (You may want to do the opposite of the `if` from the second function in the first one, to prevent overwrite.)

Comment: This will sound stupid, but I don't understand what exactly you meant by "opposite of the if from the second function in the first one" I tried something but it didn't work.

Comment: The second function only does something if the `data-text` attribute is present and has a non-blank value (`if (text)`). To avoid overwriting it, you could add the opposite to the first function: Only do something if the `data-text` property *isn't* present with a non-blank value. (`if (!element.getAttribute("data-text"))`). Or better yet, disable the buttons based on whether you've already translated that element.